# creating object of another class when initializing an object of a class

Tags: class, stepper

Here's what I want to achieve:
I'm building a class for controlling step motors. In that class I want to have a method called "init". In that method I'd like to create an object of class Tone, which I'll need to control a motor.
BUT I want to have seperate Tone class object for every object of my class that I create. How can I do it?

So, for exmaple, if I have:

```
myClass newmotor1;
memotor1.init();
```

After executing these two lines, I'd like to have my object newmotor1 (which I have, because I just created it) AND an object of class Tone, which I'll use.

Comment: Why do you want to create it in the `init` function? Why not just have one in the class already?

Comment: But I want to have seperate Tone objects for each object of my class

Comment: And? What difference does that make?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm actually new to classes, objects and all that stuff. Could you explan?

Comment: You use a class just like any other variable. Just use it in your class like any other variable.

Comment: I think I understand now, that's a good idea. I've been learning C# recently for my work, I wonder if it could be done in C# too (I'm not talking Arduino at all now, I'm just curious if similiar thing could be applied to C# program)

Comment: No idea. I have never used that inferior language ;)

Comment: Oh come on, I think it's quite good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to "create" anything. Just have an object in your class:

```
class Tone {
    public:
        void dosomething() {
            // Whatever is in here
        }
};

class MyMotor {
    public:
        Tone tone;
        void init() {
            // Nothing much else to do in here now.
        }
};
```

You then:

```
MyMotor newmotor1;
```

And you can access:

```
newmotor1.tone.dosomething();
```

Comment: That's a perfect solution. Thanks Majenko!